# Recordset.Sort method not sorting

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access

First time I've used .Sort but from Googling the following should work, but the debug print output is not sorted.

```
Function SortByYear(ByVal z As DAO.Recordset) As String
 Dim mySortedRS As DAO.Recordset
 z.Sort = "Year"
 Set mySortedRS = z
    Do
        Debug.Print mySortedRS!Year
        mySortedRS.MoveNext
    Loop Until mySortedRS.EOF
Set mySortedRS = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you

```vbs
Set mySortedRS = z
```

you are not creating a new `Recordset` object, you are simply creating a new variable that points to the existing `Recordset` object. To create a new (sorted) `Recordset` you need to use

```vbs
Set mySortedRS = z.OpenRecordset
```

For more information, see

[Recordset.Sort Property (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198077%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Aha!  I see my error. Thank you... btw I see the pop up balloon here says to avoid a thanks comment... seems very rude to do that.

Comment: @Kirk It's just an effort to cut down on "noise" in the comments. You can always say "thanks" by upvoting and/or [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).